# How to limit number of characters per line in MIcrosoft Word 2011?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a professor that asks that we limit each line to 80 characters.  I can write a script to do this, but is there a way to do it right from Microsoft Word 2011?  I need a carriage return after every 80 character line.  "\n" is what I need.

Comment: Seems like you could use a mono-spaced font like Courier of the appropriate size to get so many per inch and the set your margins accordingly.

Comment: That is what I did, but I need an actual carriage return.  /n to be exact, after every 80 characters.

Comment: Do a "Save As..." and select Plain Text. It should give you some options one of which will be that of inserting line breaks (CR/LF).

Comment: That's an odd requirement and I'm not aware of any way to achieve hard line wrapping (`\n`) in MS Word. Generally hard line wrap is a feature reserved for programmer's text editors like Notepad++.

Does he want 80-character lines specifically, or is he really trying to enforce limits on font size and margins?

Comment: He wants the 80 character lines specifically.  I know it is weird, but he seems to think it is easier for him if we turn in our code assignments as well as our written assignments this way

Comment: From @THEn:  Would [this Microsoft Support link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/144501) help? Depending on your paper size that link helps you to calculate the size of the font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to calculate, at a glance, approximately 80 characters, then I would suggest justifying the text and using a simple line break after each line to make the text extend to the width of the line.

[image: Each line is the same length regardless of number of characters. (Formatting characters have been included to guide you.)]

As above, if you have a rough idea in mind as to when 80 characters has been reached, you could always enter a line break (`Shift` + `Enter`/`Return`) in order to begin a new line, and the justification of the text will allow it all to fit uniformly across the line.

To make doubly sure that you have reached (up to) 80 characters per line, you can highlight the characters/words and click the `Word Count` function.  To perhaps speed things up, assuming you are using MS Word 2007 or 2010, hold `Alt` and press `T` then `W` to bring up the `Word Count` dialog box which will show you how many characters your highlighted section makes up.  In my example, I have highlighted four words (which total 14 characters not including spaces, or 18 characters including spaces):

[image: Word Count dialog box]

Answer (score 0):

You could insert a table and size the font and borders to only fit 80 characters.

Comment: The OP says, “I need a carriage return … "\n" is what I need.” How can your solution be used to insert the required carriage return?